# How to use this foreach to call images by id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently trying to create an image carousel and I wanted to add something like this under the carousel

[image]

The circles under the slider when you click it and it takes you to the next or previous picture
So i have a jQuery code that already moves my pictures to the next and prev by the buttons on the side but i can't relate it so that it can move the buttons and I think thats because i need to call the images there first by their ID or just a 0, 1 ,2 depending on how many pics there are so that i can connect it to jQuery and add the picture to it

This is the PHP code I use to call the pictures

```
<?php
                        if (!empty($data['images'])):
                            foreach ($data['images'] as $img) : ?>
                                <?php if (!empty($img['image'])) : ?>
                                    <div class="slide parentSlider">
                                        <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
                                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($img['image'], 'carousel-image', '', ['class' => 'img-responsive', 'data-track-content' => '']); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach;
                        endif;
                        ?>
```

Then I call the pictures on a modal and use the jQuery code

```
var id;
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).parent().index();
  id = parseInt(idx);
  $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
  $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  id++; //increment
  if (id < $('.imgs').length) {
    //get id find src
    var next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image); //add same
    $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
  }
});
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  id--; //decremnt
  if (id > -1) {
    //find image
    var next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image); //add same
    $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
  }
});
```

I was thinking to add a UL and LI  or divs so that I could use the same foreach to call the pictures but im not sure how to do it

```
//Example code i was thinking to use 
<div id="controls">
        <div id="control-container">
            <button id="slide1" class="control-button"></button>
            <button id="slide2" class="control-button"></button>
            <button id="slide3" class="control-button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery but I'm sure it most have a selector that returns an array of matching elements, much like `document.querySelectorAll()` that you could use to traverse and target the desired element.

Comment: It does return an array but I was told that you still need to configure the PHP to be able to use it since I'm not quire familiar with jQuery as much I thought I should go like this